# W3C CSS validation gives "Parse Error" for opacity

Tags: css, opacity, w3c-validation

While testing the CSS stylesheet for my personal website, the following Parse Errors appeared for the `opacity` properties. Why is this? Isn't `opacity=70` a perfect  property for filter alpha for IE8 support?

```
.image-section #sliderLeft  Parse Error opacity=70)
.image-section #sliderRight Parse Error opacity=70)
.image-section #caption Parse Error [empty string]
```

Here is the CSS Code in which the error appears :

```
.image-section #caption
{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    bottom: 4px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background: #474747;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.image-section #sliderLeft
{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: 25px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -25px;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.7;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
    border: 0;
}

.image-section #sliderRight
{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: 25px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -25px;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 0.7;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
    border: 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems that there's some other code for the opacity in IE8: `-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";`. Alsom the order seems to be important then. Check this link: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/opacity/

Comment: OP is not asking "how do I make it work". He is asking "Why W3C's jigsaw validation service doesn't accept this?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

W3C uses some parsing engine which does not allow a syntax like `alpha(opacity=70)`. There is no css property in the standard that would allow such a definition format.

I cannot reproduce

> Parse Error [empty string]

in your `.image-section #caption` using

> http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input

Answer (score 3):

Neither the syntax nor the `filter` property are valid CSS. Doesn't mean they don't work with IE8, though.

Comment: Nitpicking: A `filter` **property** is perfectly valid CSS 3. `filter` is not a valid property **value**, though. http://css3.com/css-filter/